# Are there any tools to read javascript code easily?

Tags: javascript

when i visit website, sometimes i find all js code in a file written in one line.(i use chrome Devtools to read them)
is there any tool to show it in multi-line way so it would be easy to read?

Comment: Yes: The Chrome developer tool itself has a button that formats code.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the "Sources" window, it says:

```
      {}     Line 1, Column 1
```

Click the "{}". That will format the code into a more readable format.